# Android App Install Script Mechanism / Method

Tags: android, installation

Is there any mechanism and / or programming practice on android to execute one-time install / update scripts? It may seem a very basic question but a google search didn't help.

Say my app uses a database and there needs to be a table for constant values (such as country names, city names, etc.) App should create a database and write the constant values in it, but should do it only if app is freshly installed or updated.

Should I;

a) Put a function in MainActivity to check if database and data in it is in place

b) Put a function in MainActivity to write a small chunk of file with current software version, then check it in each run to see if it is a fresh install or an update (of course it will first check the file, then write it if not present)

c) Or is there any other defacto method for this to run in each install and / or update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you will install and what change in your database.

If you just generate a new Apk and run it, it will update and not remove the previously data, but if you remove the APP and install the new, the data will be removed.

Other thing you should consider is the version of the Database, if the installed version is lower than the needed in your new application.

Note that you need to get a database object either with dbhelper.getWriteableDatabase() or dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(). Creating a SQLiteOpenHelper object alone is not enough.

The control of that depends on what are you using to create the database, for example, if you are creating with a SQLiteOpenHelper a method like this normally is used:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}
```

**Edit:**
When which method is called ?

On code:

```
DbName = "teste.db"
DbVersion = 1
```

On device:
     none db

**^ Will invoke onCreate.**

On code:

```
DbName = "teste.db"
DbVersion = 2
```

On device:

```
 DbName = "teste.db"
 DbVersion = 1
```

**^ Will invoke onUpgrade**

On code:

```
DbName = "teste.db"
DbVersion = 1
```

On device:

```
 DbName = "teste.db"
 DbVersion = 2
```

**^ Will invoke onDowngrade**

On code:

```
DbName = "anotherName.db"
DbVersion = 1
```

On device:

```
 DbName = "teste.db"
 DbVersion = 1
```

**^ Will invoke onCreate**

Comment: Thanks. That covers database versioning. What about I need to do this check for any other purpose? For example cached files in device needs to be flushed after upgrade? Is there any native mechanism for that?

Comment: You can put any logic into onUpgrade, so if the database is newer than the installed, the code will be executed, normally in the method onUpgrade we manually drop the tables and create the new tables, but you don't need to drop they, if you prefer do an Alter Table or whatever you want.  To manually check the version, just instantiate your database and call the method `getVersion();`

Comment: You can also create an onDowngrade method, for the opposite situation

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed.

Comment: I know that I have already accepted the answer, but a specific question popped into my mind about this. When does onCreate and onUpdate methods gets invoked? Do they invoke automatically or do I have to invoke them manually? I have instantiated the dbhelper class in my MainActivity but it does not seem to invoke onCreate method automatically (I am uninstalling the app from device before trying this).

Comment: The mehod onCreate is invoked if the Database that you defined with a name and versions does not exists, the onUpgrade is invoked when the database exists, but the version is lower than the version on your code, exists the onDowngrade method, he is invoked when your version on code is lesser of the existent, i will update the answer with an example

Comment: I read your edit. That is very interesting, because I have a `Log.v` statement in my SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate() method and it does not gets logged in logcat. 

I also have this line of code in my MainActivity.onCreate() and MainActivity.onResume() methods: 

`FileDbHelper db = new FileDbHelper(getApplicationContext());`

I suppose this line is mandatory for db to be recognised by the app, isn't it?

Comment: Your class is extending the SQLiteOpenHelper right ? How are your constructor method ?

Comment: Right, it does. It looks like this: 

`public class FileDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "file.db";

    public FileDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }`

Comment: seems right to me, follow the steps from the docs [link] (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=pt-br)

Comment: OK; got it. It turned out that you need to use dbhelper.getWritableDatabase() or dbhelper.getReadableDatabase() in order to get the database instantiated. Creating an SQLiteOpenHelper object is not enough. I will add this detail to your answer with your permission :)